# How do I force the display of validation errors?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a pretty standard Material Form and everything is sweet.

When I submit my form, I optionally get validation errors, I loop through these matching the key to the control, then set the validation error. Like this with the loop removed.

I don't really think it matters, but here is the relevant part.

```
 const control = this.form.get(key);
 if (control) {
     control.setErrors({
         server: response.validationErrors[key]
     },{
         emitEvent: true
     });

     // I was trying things like
     // control.markAsTouched() but it did nothing
 }
```

At this point,  my form is displaying Red Fields which is great.

[image: shows red fields]

But it doesn't show the error message until I interact with the field, which is an annoyance.

[image: shows red fields after interaction displaying the error]

However, the thing that might be causing this, is that I am not using `<form (submit)="onSubmit(model)">` syntax.  Therefor on my buttons i am not using `type=submit` and `attr.form="my-form"`

So at no point is the form traditionally submitted.  I believe this may be an issue here.

If I read the material [Form Field Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages).  It tells me:

> Error messages can be shown under the form field underline by adding
>   mat-error elements inside the form field. Errors are hidden initially
>   and will be displayed on invalid form fields after the user has
>   interacted with the element or the parent form has been submitted.

Notice that last line? I find it hard to properly understand it.

Question:

**Is there a mechanism that allows me to force the display of these validation errors straight away without the interaction?**

Comment: Yes, this is the default behavior of angular material, but you can write an error state matcher to achieve what you want: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: In general, a simple `this.form.markAllAsTouched()` must be work, BTW try markAsTouched() **before** setErrors or enclosed by a setTimeout `setTimeout(()=>{control.markAsTouched()}`

Comment: form.markAllAsTouched() doesn't work at least with latest angular.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/voepaombnnb?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)

here is your html template file... **[errorStateMatcher]="matcher"** is important.

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl"
       [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
          Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
          Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

and in your **ErroStateMatcher** class file..

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
      isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
     const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
      return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
      } 
}
```